# looping string list and get no record count from table

Tags: string, list, loops, plsql, procedure

I have string values get from a table using listagg(column,',')
so I want to loop this string list and set into where clause for another table
then I want to get a count when no any records in the table (Number of times with no record)

I'm writing this inside the plsql procedure

| order_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | test1 |
| 20 | test2 |
| 22 | test3 |
| 25 | test4 |

| col_id | product | order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pro1 | 10 |
| 2 | pro2 | 30 |
| 3 | pro2 | 38 |

expected result : count(Number of times with no record) in 2nd table

count = 3

because there is no any record of 20,22,25 order ids in 2nd table

only have record for order_id - 10

my queries

```
SELECT listagg(ord.order_id,',')
        into wk_orderids
        from orders ord, 
        where ord.id_no = wk_id_no;



loop

-- do my stuff

end loop
```

wk_orderids values = ('10','20','22','25')

I want to loop this one(wk_orderids) and set it one by one into a select query where clause
then want to get the count Number of times with no record

Comment: please edit the question and 1) show all table definitions, 2) Sample table data, 3) expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count `ORDER_ID`s in the 2nd table that don't exist in `ORDER_ID` column of the 1st table, then your current approach looks as if you were given a task to do that in the most complicated way. Aggregating values, looping through them, adding values into a `where` clause (which then requires dynamic SQL) ... OK, but - why? Why not simply

```
select count(*)
from (select order_id from first_table
      minus
      select order_id from second_table
     );
```